# how to call multiple functions in a single function by passing parameters

Tags: jquery, html

I am a beginner in javascript. I am trying to pass multiple functions in a single function by passing parameter.I want to write a single function for both. here are my two js function code. Please help me with solving this.
there are 2 fields and the save button of these two are initially display: none; When I click on edit button will change to display:inline-block; Initially fields will be disabled after clicking on edit fields will be enabled to edit. Also when I click on edit the "edit" text gets changes to "Cancel" and when I again click on Cancel the text gets changes to "eidt"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UogL3.png)

```js
$('#edit_data_info').on('click', function() {
  var text = $('#edit_data_info').text();
  if (text === "Edit") {
    $(this).html('Cancel');
  } else {
    $(this).text('Edit');
  }
  toggleInfo();
});

function toggleInfo() {
  $("#save-name").toggle();
  $(".heighlight").toggleClass("heighlights");
}

$('#edit_data_email').on('click', function() {
  var text = $('#edit_data_email').text();
  if (text === "Edit") {
    $(this).html('Cancel');
  } else {
    $(this).text('Edit');
  }
  toggleEmail();
});

function toggleEmail() {
  $("#save-email").toggle();
  $(".heighlight-email").toggleClass("heighlights");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-acc-details heighlight" role="form" id="demo">
  <div class="info-details">
    <div class="info">
      <h1 class="personal-info">Personal Information</h1>
      <button type="button" class="edit-data" id='edit_data_info'>Edit</button>
    </div>
    <div class="fill-information">
      <div class="fill-form-info form-group col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="my-info form-control" id="change_fname" value="john" pattern="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{1,20}$" title="Atleast two Characters" disabled required/>
      </div>
      <div class="fill-form-info form-group col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="my-info form-control" id="change_lname" value="grey" pattern="^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{1,20}$" title="Atleast two characters" disabled required/>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn-submit btn btn-primary" id="save-name">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<form class="form-acc-details heighlight-email" role="form" class="recorrect_email">
  <div class="info-email">
    <div class="info">enter code here
      <h1 class="personal-info">Email Address</h1>
      <button type="button" class="edit-data" id='edit_data_email'>Edit</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-information btn-lg" data- toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id='change-pwd'>Change Password</button>
    </div>
    <div class="fill-information">
      <div class="fill-form-info form-group col-md-4">
        <input type="email" class="my-info form-control" value="Abcd@gmail.com" id="change_email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" title="characters followed by an @ sign, followed by more characters, and then a .dot and must not contain capital letters" disabled required/></div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn-submit btn btn-primary" id="save-email">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I believe you want to create one function toggleElement(parameter) where the parameter is the element which you want to toggle the class and the visibility, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, Exactly I want to do like this.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this :)

```
$('#edit_data_email, #edit_data_info').on('click', function () 
{
    var button=${this}.attr('id');
    var text=$(this).text();
    if(text === "Edit")
    {
        $(this).html('Cancel');
    } 
    else
    {
        $(this).text('Edit');
    }
    toggleElement(button);
});

function toggleElement(button)
{
    if(button == 'edit_data_email') {
        $("#save-email").toggle();
        $(".heighlight-email").toggleClass("heighlights");
    }
    if(button == 'edit_data_info') {
        $("#save-name").toggle();
        $(".heighlight").toggleClass("heighlights");
    }
}
```

Comment: Real nice. I changed it a bit more: https://codepen.io/Kathara/pen/rYqoqe But yours is better. ^^

Comment: no... something like this
<body>

<p>Setting a default value to a function parameter.</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<p id="demo1"></p>

<script>
function myFunction(x, y) {
    if (y === undefined) {
        y = 0;
    }    
    return x * y;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myFunction(4, 12);
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = myFunction(4, 10);
</script>

</body>

Comment: I want to write these below programs in one function.

Comment: Suppose I hv 2 funcs wid different id's.Here I am showing only 1 funcn becoz of character limit.These two functions i want to write in on by passing parameters. $('#edit_data_info').click(function(){     if($(this).parents('.infodetails').find('#change_fname,#change_lname').hasClass('readonly'{$(this).parents('.infodetails').find('#change_fname,#change_lname').removeClass('readonly');$("#change_fname,#change_lname").prop("disabled",true);}else{$(this).parents('.infodetails').find('#change_fname,#change_lname').addClass('readonly');$("#change_fname,#change_lname").prop("disabled",false);}});